# sending RMCP ping

Tags: c#, powershell

i want to send RMCP ping in powerShell (or c#)
as i understood it is a ping to port 623
how can i do it? send ping to port and get the resoponse?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

RMCP stands for Remote Management and Control Protocol.  This is VERY different then ICMP (Protocol & Ping).  You are going to have to assemble your own `UDP RMCP Ping` packet that adheres to the Protocol defined under [DMTF ASF Releases](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/asf), as I am not aware of any libararies that do this currently.

Specifically under the heading `3.2.2.3 RMCP Data` in version 2.0.0.